# php require_once

Tags: php

i have this in the first page "login.php"

```
<?php
session_start();
$msg='';
if ((isset($_POST))&& (!empty($_POST)))
{
require_once('log.php') or die(mysql_error());
$p=md5($pass);
if (login($login,$p))
{
    header('location:index.php');;
}
else 
{
    $msg="Login ou mot de passe incorrect";
}
}
?>
```

log.php:

```
$req="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE login='$e' and password='$p'";
$res=mysql_query($req) or die(mysql_error()."\n".$req);

if(mysql_num_rows($res)!=0)
{
    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $_SESSION['adm']=array('code'=>$data['code'], 'login'=>$data['login']);
    return true;
    mysql_close();
}
else return false;
}?>
```

and if i test the first page "login.php" i got this:

> Warning: require_once(1): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\login.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '1'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\login.php on line 6

Comment: check your log.php is in the same directory where login.php reside. Also check the file permission.

Comment: Check the file name and location whether it is correctly located at the given location

Comment: **[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code.](http://bit.ly/phpmsql)** They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the **[red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)**? Learn about _[prepared statements](http://j.mp/T9hLWi)_ instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: i checked! everything seems correct! i cant see where the problem is!?

Comment: This `SELECT * FROM admin WHERE login='$e' and password='$p'` allows SQL injection attacks. Please read up on them. Try removing the ` or die()` after the require_once, it will cause an exit if the file is not there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure you have the right location, you can use dirname

```
dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.php'
```

[Check this out for a documentation and explanation](http://www.kavoir.com/2010/02/php-why-you-should-use-dirname__file__-include-php-instead-of-just-include-php.html)

Answer (score 0):

require_once is not a function. What is happening is that your require_once line evaluates like this:

```
 require_once ( log.php or die() );
```

which means it tries to open a file named 1.

You don't need to use die after require_once, it will fail and die by itself.